# Aggregate interval data by binning to create time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame containing records on the start time, end time, user, product and usage rate. A user is capable of using the same product multiple times at different rates. I want to transform this DataFrame into a timeseries dataset where for each user, bins of 4 hours are created in which the usage rate is added up. As start and end times can overlap with the bin boundaries, fractional usage over that bin would need to be calculated and each product receives their own column.

**Original DataFrame:**

| start | end | user | product | usage_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | A | X_1 | 10 |
| 8 | 15 | A | X_1 | 20 |
| 3 | 7 | B | X_1 | 3 |
| 3 | 8 | B | X_2 | 70 |

**Desired output:**

| user | bin | start | end | X_1 | X_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0-4 | 0 | 4 | 30 | 0 |
| A | 4-8 | 4 | 8 | 40 | 0 |
| A | 8-12 | 8 | 12 | 120 | 0 |
| A | 12-16 | 12 | 16 | 60 | 0 |
| B | 0-4 | 0 | 4 | 3 | 70 |
| B | 4-8 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 280 |

I've tried to use `pd.cut` to create bins, but only manage to create only DataFrames where the start time matches and/or the end time matches, but not the bins in between. I want to prevent using for loops as these can become quite slow when expanding this to 10k users and 20 products. The process I thought of first duplicates each row for the number of time bins required (0-4, 4-8, 8-12 for the first record), calculates the duration within that bin, multiplies duration by `usage_rate` to get `used_in_bin` value, then `groupby(['user', 'bin'])` and retrieves the sum of those `used_in_bin` values. Then the last step would be to pivot the product name and values to get the table.

The hard part is that I'm stuck creating the time bins for time ranges (either datetime or numerical). In what way can I create duplicate records for the missing bins between the start and end time of my range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have is described by mathematical step functions, and [staircase](https://staircase.dev) has been built upon pandas and numpy for this purpose.

**setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "start":[1,8,3,3],
        "end":[12,15,7,8],
        "user":["A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "product":["X_1", "X_1", "X_1", "X_2"],
        "usage_rate":[10,20,3,70]
    }
)
```

**solution**

We'll create a step function for each user and product.  A step function is represented by the `staircase.Stairs` class.  This class is to *staircase* as `Series` is to *pandas*.  To do this we group the dataframe on these variables and pass the sub-dataframes to the [`Stairs` constructor](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/reference/api/staircase.Stairs.__init__.html#staircase.Stairs.__init__).

```
import staircase as sc

stepfunctions = df.groupby(["user", "product"]).apply(sc.Stairs, "start", "end", "usage_rate")
```

Our `stepfunctions` variable looks like this.  It is a series, with a multi-index, and values are `Stairs` objects.

```
user  product
A     X_1        <staircase.Stairs, id=2516839332104>
B     X_1        <staircase.Stairs, id=2516834889160>
      X_2        <staircase.Stairs, id=2516835627464>
dtype: object
```

There are many things you can do with step functions in `staircase` including plotting.

```
stepfunctions["A", "X_1"].plot(style="hlines")
```

[image: usage rate for user A and product X_1 as a step function]

What you are wanting to do is [create bins and integrate](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/reference/api/staircase.StairsSlicer.integral.html#staircase.StairsSlicer.integral) (find the area under) these step functions.  For a step function `sf` this means the following calculation

```
sf.slice([0,4,8,12,16]).integral()
```

We can use `pandas.Series.apply` to do this for all our step functions.

```
binned = stepfunctions.apply(lambda sf: sf.slice([0,4,8,12,16]).integral())
```

The `binned` variable will we a dataframe, with the same index as `stepfunctions`, with a column for each bin interval

```
               [0, 4)  [4, 8)  [8, 12)  [12, 16)
user product                                   
A    X_1        30.0    40.0    120.0      60.0
B    X_1         3.0     9.0      0.0       0.0
     X_2        70.0   280.0      0.0       0.0
```

To get this data in a [tidy format](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) the following can be used

```
tidy_result = binned.melt(ignore_index=False).rename({"variable":"bin"}).reset_index()
```

The `tidy_result` dataframe will look like this:

```
   user product       bin  value
0     A     X_1    [0, 4)   30.0
1     B     X_1    [0, 4)    3.0
2     B     X_2    [0, 4)   70.0
3     A     X_1    [4, 8)   40.0
4     B     X_1    [4, 8)    9.0
5     B     X_2    [4, 8)  280.0
6     A     X_1   [8, 12)  120.0
7     B     X_1   [8, 12)    0.0
8     B     X_2   [8, 12)    0.0
9     A     X_1  [12, 16)   60.0
10    B     X_1  [12, 16)    0.0
11    B     X_2  [12, 16)    0.0
```

This may be enough for your purposes.  If you want to get it in the exact format you have submitted, then this should be easy enough:

- use `tidy_result.pivot(index=["user", "bin"], columns="product")` to turn the product column into columns for each product.  Fill `NA` values for `A` and `X_2` with 0.
- use `tidy_result["start"] = pd.IntervalIndex(tidy_result["bin"]).left` etc

**To recap, the solution (after imports) boils down to the following three lines**

```
stepfunctions = df.groupby(["user", "product"]).apply(sc.Stairs, "start", "end", "usage_rate")
binned = stepfunctions.apply(lambda sf: sf.slice([0,4,8,12,16]).integral())
tidy_result = binned.melt(ignore_index=False).rename({"variable":"bin"}).reset_index()
```

**note**:
I am the creator of staircase.  Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.